# How to catch the longest sequence of a group

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, cs50, dna-sequence

The task is to find the longest sequence of a group

for instance, given DNA sequence: `"AGATCAGATCTTTTTTCTAATGTCTAGGATATATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC"`
and it has 7 occurrences of AGATC. `(AGATC)` matches all occurrences.
Is it possible to write a regular expression that catches only the longest sequence, i.e. `AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC` in the given text?
If this is not possible only with regex, how can I iterate through each sequence (i.e. 1st sequence is `AGATCAGATC`, 2nd - `AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC` et cetera) in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
import re

sequence = "AGATCAGATCTTTTTTCTAATGTCTAGGATATATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', sequence)

# To find the longest subsequence
longest = max(matches, key=len)
```

Explanation:

*Non-capturing group `(?:AGATC)+`*

- `+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible.
- `AGATC` matches the characters AGATC literally (case sensitive)

Result:

```
# print(matches)
['AGATCAGATC', 'AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC']

# print(longest)
'AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC'
```

You can test the regex [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/TaBVnx/1).

Comment: Such a short and elegant solution! Thank you a lot

Comment: This is a good solution, probably the one I would use, but it does not answer the question, "Is it possible to write a regular expression that catches only the longest sequence?".

Comment: @CarySwoveland Well, I have taken a alternate approach for the question even this doesn't find the longest single subsequence using regex only  but it does find the all the consecutive subsequences of longest possible length, therefore we can easily select the longest subsequence using just the max function.

Answer (score 2):

The central question is, "Is it possible to write a regular expression that catches only the longest sequence?" The answer is "yes":

```
import re

s = 'AGATC_AGATCAGATC_AGATCAGATCAGATC_AGATC_AGATCAGATC'

m = re.search(r'((?:AGATC)+)(?!.*\1)', s)
print m.group() if m else ''
  #=> "AGATCAGATCAGATC"
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UQV4WI/4/)<sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub>[Python demo](http://tpcg.io/cr8wluEW)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(            begin capture group 1
  (?:AGATC)  match 'AGATC' in a non-capture group
  +          execute the non-capture group 1+ times
)            end capture group 1
(?!          begin a negative lookahead
  .*         match 0+ characters
  \1         match the content of capture group 1
)            end the negative lookahead
```

For the string `s` above, `AGATC` would first be matched but the negative lookahead would find `AGATC` as the first part of `AGATCAGATC`, so the tentative match would be rejected. Then `AGATCAGATC` would be matched, but the negative lookahead would find `AGATCAGATC` as the first part of `AGATCAGATCAGATC` so that tentative match would also be rejected. Next, `AGATCAGATCAGATC` would be matched and accepted, as the negative lookahead would not find that match later in the string. (`re.findall`, unlike `re.search`, would also match `AGATCAGATC` at the end of the string.)

If `re.findall` were used there may be multiple matches after the longest one (see the last test string at the link to the regex demo), but the lengths of the matches are non-decreasing from the first to the last. Therefore, the first match, obtained using `re.search` is a longest match.

Comment: Good answer @caryswoveland +1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.finditer()` to iterate over all matches.  Then use `max()` with a key function to find the longest.  Make it a function so you can use different groups.

```
import re

def find_longest(sequence, group):
    # build pattern
    pattern = fr"(?:{group})+"

    # iterate over all matches
    matches = (match[0] for match in re.finditer(pattern, sequence))

    # find the longest
    return max(matches, key=len)

seq = "AGATCAGATCTTTTTTCTAATGTCTAGGATATATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC"

find_longest(seq, "AGATC")
```