# Including / excluding capturing group affects search result

Tags: python, regex, cs50

**TASK**

Find the longest consecutive sequence of a string within a string.

For e.g., given DNA sequence: `AGATCAGATCTTTTTTCTAATGTCTAGGATATATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC`, find the longest consecutive sequence of `AGATC`.

**WHAT I TRIED**

Using `search = re.findall(r'(AGATC)+', DNAsequence)` only returns me strings with 1 consecutive sequence, e.g. `['AGATC', 'AGATC', 'AGATC', ...]`

I found out I needed to use the non-capturing group `?:` in order to get the expected output. `search = re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', DNAsequence)` returns me the expected `['AGATC', 'AGATCAGATCAGATC', 'AGATC', ...]`

**WHAT I NEED HELP WITH**

Why do I need to use the non-capturing group expression in order to get more than 1 consecutive sequence? Shouldn't `(AGATC)+` on its own already give the expected output? From what I understand, using capturing groups or not also shouldn't affect the search result.

**NOTE**

This question is highly related to [How to catch the longest sequence of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62078827/how-to-catch-the-longest-sequence-of-a-group), but the top answer didn't explain why the non-capturing group has to be used in the syntax. I am unable to add my question as a comment, so I have to create a new post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non capturing group is necessary, because your regex pattern specifies the repetitition of `AGATC`, which be default will tell `re.findall` to return as match whatever appears in the capture group.  To further explain this, the capture group in `(AGATC)+` will only return the *last* match in the case of more than one `AGATC`.  This means that `AGATC` is the longest match which would ever be returned.  By turning off the capture group, it allows `re.findall` to default to returning the entire match, which is what you want.

```
seq = "AGATCAGATCTTTTTTCTAATGTCTAGGATATATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC"
matches = re.findall(r'(AGATC)+', seq)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['AGATC', 'AGATC']
```

However, turning off the capture group:

```
seq = "AGATCAGATCTTTTTTCTAATGTCTAGGATATATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC"
matches = re.findall(r'(?:AGATC)+', seq)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['AGATCAGATC', 'AGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATC']
```